# Understanding the need for extra function in function closure exercise

Tags: javascript, function, closures

This is an exercise from "Object oriented javascript" in the section about closures. I'm having trouble understanding the need for the highlighted extra function used to "return x;". Tried using return x; directly from the function accepting the parameter x and it doesn't work but I can't grasp   why it makes it work.
Thanks

```
function F() {
  var arr = [], i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr[i] = (function (x) {
      **return function ()** {
        return x;
      };
    }(i));
  }
  return arr;
}


> var arr = F();
> arr[0]();
0
> arr[1]();
1
> arr[2]();
2
```

Comment: it makes _i_ "private" inside as _x_, otherwise x would ~always == the last value of _i_

Comment: Common question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example